# requestForMe error when calling the Facebook Graph (iOS) Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've downloaded this template from GitHub:
https://github.com/LunarFlash/MatchMe

The template uses facebook & parse to recreate a tinder style app

I've since updated the parse and facebook utils to the current version but i'm having issues with this code here:

```
#pragma mark - Helper Method
- (void) updateUserInformation {
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [FBSDKGraphRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    // NSLog(@"result:%@", result);

    if (!error) {
        NSDictionary *userDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
```

Here are the frameworks i've used at the top:

```
#import "YILoginViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "YIConstants.h"
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

The error i'm getting is at the 3rd line of the code "requestForMe", Xcode says "No known class method for selector 'requestForMe", any help on fixing this will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `[FBRequest requestForMe]` is not supported in the newer SDK versions anymore. This was a helper method to create a call to `/me`. You can easily replace this.

Please note there are more [breaking changes between 3.x and 4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x#3to4), so you can't just replace the SDKs. The code needs to be updated as well and as you've noticed, some methods changed.